# Github markdown, syntax highlight of code blocks in the table cell

Tags: github, html-table, markdown, syntax-highlighting, github-flavored-markdown

Markdown has pipe table syntax but it's not enough for some cases.

```
| table | syntax | without multiline cell content |
```

So, we can use HTML table tags.

````html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
   ```csharp
   const int x = 3;
   const string y = "foo";
   readonly Object obj = getObject();
   ```
</td>
<td>
  ```nemerle
  def x : int = 3;
  def y : string = "foo";
  def obj : Object = getObject();
  ```
</td>
<td>
  Variables defined with <code>def</code> cannot be changed once defined. This is similar to <code>readonly</code> or <code>const</code> in C# or <code>final</code> in Java. Most variables in Nemerle aren't explicitly typed like this.
</td>
</tr>
````

But some time ago syntax highlighting was broken and this [wiki page](https://github.com/rsdn/nemerle/wiki/CSharp-Similarities-and-Differences/fe35c49e0a1fbb0604552f0105dae3cd606ce08d) looks ugly now. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `<pre>` in tables, as teh_senaus said.  But if you do that, syntax highlighting won't work... or will it?

Through random experimentation I found that GitHub allows specifying it with `<pre lang="csharp">`.  This has the same effect that ```` ```csharp ```` does of setting the syntax highlighting to C#.

This isn't really documented anywhere in GitHub's help center, nor in [linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist)'s documentation.  But it works, even inside of tables.

So for your example table, the new code would be as follows:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
   <pre lang="csharp">
   const int x = 3;
   const string y = "foo";
   readonly Object obj = getObject();
   </pre>
</td>
<td>
  <pre lang="nemerle">
  def x : int = 3;
  def y : string = "foo";
  def obj : Object = getObject();
  </pre>
</td>
<td>
  Variables defined with <code>def</code> cannot be changed once defined. This is similar to <code>readonly</code> or <code>const</code> in C# or <code>final</code> in Java. Most variables in Nemerle aren't explicitly typed like this.
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add a blank line between the `<td>` and the code block.

Here's the fixed markdown:

````
<table>
<tr>
<td>

  ```csharp
  const int x = 3;
  const string y = "foo";
  readonly Object obj = getObject();
  ```
</td>
<td>

  ```nemerle
  def x : int = 3;
  def y : string = "foo";
  def obj : Object = getObject();
  ```
</td>
<td>
  Variables defined with <code>def</code> cannot be changed once defined. This is similar to <code>readonly</code> or <code>const</code> in C# or <code>final</code> in Java. Most variables in Nemerle aren't explicitly typed like this.
</td>
</tr>
</table>
````

and the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<pre>`. Syntax highlighting won't work, but at least it will be formatted properly.

```
<td><pre>
   const int x = 3;
   const string y = "foo";
   readonly Object obj = getObject();
</pre></td>
```

Comment: @Alvaro In case you are interested, there actually is a way to do it (`<pre lang="csharp">`).  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29981184/3991344).

Answer (score 2):

Another way is using multiple `` ` `` and `<br>`, but Syntax highlighting won't work .

```
|1|2|3
-|-|-
`const int x = 3;`<br>`   const string y = "foo";`<br>`readonly Object obj =getObject();`|`def x : int = 3;`<br>`def y : string = "foo";`<br>`def obj : Object = getObject(); `|Variables defined with `def` cannot be changed once defined. This is similar to `readonly` or `const` in C# or `final` in Java. Most variables in Nemerle aren't explicitly typed like this.explicitly typed like this.
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the *[backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27678052/104380)* around your code, while wrapping it all with a `<pre>` tag, like so:

```html
<pre lang=html>`<input readonly>`</pre>
```

---

Here's a screenshot of how it renders, from my own use case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also :

```
A | B | C
-- | -- | --
x | y | Some code : <pre lang=php>function sayHello($someArg)</pre>
1 | 2 | 3
```