# Insert code content with highlightings in a table using the Markdown syntax in a Github Gist

Tags: github, markdown, gist

How do I insert code content with highlighting in a table using the Markdown syntax in a Github Gist.  This is the final result I would like to obtain:

[image]

#### The problem in details:

This is the basic markdown syntax to create a table with simple content:

```
PHPStructuredData | Plugin | Microdata | RDFa Lite 1.1
--- | --- | --- | ---
php code here | php code here | html code here | html code here
```

The result will be :
[image]

The problem is when you need to insert code content with highlighting in a table:

````
PHPStructuredData | Plugin | Microdata | RDFa Lite 1.1
--- | --- | --- | ---
```php
<?php
$sd->property('url')->display();
?>
``` | php code here | html code here | html code here
````

The non wanted result will be:
[image]

Comment: Can you paste some code that you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution [Github markdown, syntax highlight of code blocks in the table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878143/github-markdown-syntax-highlight-of-code-blocks-in-the-table-cell) but as you can see the syntax highlighting doesn't work as expected.